# phpMyAdmin does not have same data as MySQL command line?

Tags: mysql, php

This is very strange, and troubling. As of 30 minutes ago, phpMyAdmin is not displaying the same records as the command line, and my php pages which connect to the DB are giving inconsistent results. A change I make in phpMyAdmin does not show up when I check it in MySQL, and vice versa.

Any ideas on why this might be happening and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some examples?

Comment: I put in some on a comment below. Basically changes I made in phpMyAdmin (schema change, or in-line editing, or deleting rows) would show as normal, even after logging out and back in, or browsing to different databases. But they did not register when browsing the same records in the command line. Very weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are connecting to at least two different databases.

Comment: This sounds like it is the issue exactly--or that there's a cluster that's out of sync.

Comment: There's only one MySQL server running. I don't see how that could be the problem. How do I tell if a cluster is out of sync and how do I fix it?

Comment: And now it's back to working properly. So I have to think that it's something getting out of sync somewhere. Any ideas on what to investigate?

Comment: There's no syncing between MySQL and phpMyAdmin. Is this a system you set up yourself? Or is someone else doing the admining? It sounds like a replicated system of some sort.

Comment: My partner and I are the only admins, we set it up. I know that phpMyAdmin shouldn't sync. That's why this was so weird. I have no idea why it would have happened. The changes, i.e. new records, were visible in phpMyAdmin after logging out and logging back in, browsing different databases, etc. But they did not show up when browsing the command line for a while, and then just came back.